# Blender Freezing Around 3 Minutes of Being Open

Tags: performance, windows

So, here's my issue.

When I open Blender (either through a desktop shortcut or through file explorer) it opens up normally.  However, when I give any sort of input, such as selecting the cube or clicking on any tools, it freezes and I get an infinite load symbol, as well as "Blender (Not Responding)" on the top of the application.  It never fully crashes or closes itself, so I don't get a crash report.

When I open it through Windows PowerShell, however, it will run significantly longer before inevitably freezing in the same way.  I can maybe create a few shapes and add a modifier before it grinds to a halt.

I have reinstalled twice now, both times making certain all files were fully deleted from my computer.  I've restarted, shut down, etc.  I'm no tech pro nor have I been using Blender very long so there is likely things I have yet to try yet; if you have obvious (or non obvious) suggestions, shoot.  I'm out of ideas for what to do, or what could have caused this.  This issue occurred 3 days ago, and I hadn't downloaded anything new on my computer during the time before that.

Blender has crashed for me in the past when doing performance heavy stuff, like carrying out fluid simulations or previewing animations, but never has it crashed/froze for no reason before 3 days ago.  I have been using Blender for 4 hours daily for about a month now.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Not pictured is, I have a GeForce GTX 1050 graphics card.
I am running Windows 10, as well.
[image]

Comment: This is a localized problem on your system. There are other support sites for these kind of questions. If you think it is a bug inside blender and can be reproduced on other systems, you can open a bug report. If it is only on your machine than most likely the issue is in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I know only a small amount of Blender problems.
But I was crashing recently and it was due to using experimental mode.
I went back to gpu supported and have it working well now.